# Checking if current user can view list in SharePoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, csom

How do I determine if the current user can view list items or read a list in SharePoint Online / Office365?

I have some working code that returns the lists

```
// Retrieve all lists from the server. 
        context.Load(web.Lists,
                     lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                                            list => list.Id,                                                
                                            list => list.Hidden,
                                            list => list.BaseTemplate,
                                            list => list.BaseType));

        // Execute query. 
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        // Enumerate the web.Lists. 
        foreach (List list in web.Lists)
        {
            if (list.Hidden ||
                list.BaseType != BaseType.GenericList) continue;
           // .... check permissions here before adding ...
            names.Add(list.Id.ToString(), list.Title);
        }
```

But I don't know how to test that they current user can access the list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [List.EffectiveBasePermissions property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.effectivebasepermissions.aspx) to retrieve the effective
  permissions on the list that are assigned to *the current user*
- Use [BasePermissions.Has method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.basepermissions.has.aspx) by specifying [PermissionKind.ViewListItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.permissionkind.aspx) to
  determine whether current user could access List

**Modified example**

```
ctx.Load(web.Lists,
           lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                                  list => list.Id,
                                  list => list.Hidden,
                                  list => list.BaseTemplate,
                                  list => list.BaseType,
                                  list => list.EffectiveBasePermissions));

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (List list in web.Lists)
{
   if (list.Hidden ||
         list.BaseType != BaseType.GenericList) continue;

   if (!list.EffectiveBasePermissions.Has(PermissionKind.ViewListItems)) continue; //verity List permissions

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider doing this at the group level.  This would require you set access either based on this group or layered on top of existing group access, but that's pretty straightforward (I can go into more detail there if you need).  Here are some benefits of this approach:

- you could tie a single group to multiple lists so your code might peform better
- technically, each list item could have different security, so checking each item individually could perform poorly

These may not apply to you, but what does is that it's relatively easy to check if users are in a particular group.  Here's an example function that will return all the users in a group.  You would likely want to cache this somewhere and check the current user against it.

```
    public List<User> GetGroupUsersList(string GroupName)
    {
        var retval = new List<User>();

        ClientContext context = GetContext();
        var groupList = context.Web.SiteGroups;

        context.Load(groupList);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        var grp = groupList.Where(x => x.Title == GroupName).FirstOrDefault();
        context.Load(grp, y => y.Title, y => y.Users);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        if (grp != null && grp.Users != null)
        {
            foreach (var usr in grp.Users)
            {
                retval.Add(usr);
            }
        }

        return retval;

    }
```